# Change content via php in [if condition]

Tags: php, html, css

I want make function in php,  when url have contains after `?` like this `...com?lang=en` then show `echo "I am english language";` `else {echo "nothing";}`

Overall I want fetch current url string in php and then make function on that as above.

So, I created this code but unfortunately it not works ; something I am doing wrong. Stackoverflow developer wanna I help how I make as like this.

My code is :

```
if (!isset($_GET['lang=en']) || !isset($_GET['lang=in']) ) {
        echo "English";
    } else { echo "nothing";}
```

It above not works.
When url like `example.com?lang=en` then show `english` else `none`

Please help how I make this correct.

Thank you

**Note: this question is not duplicate please don't marks as duplicate / spam 
bcz I already fetch all post related this on stackoverflow but it was not helpful. Ans I I belive there is required this type of questions**

Comment: `$_GET['lang']` will hold the value `en` or whatever, if it is set. `$_GET['lang=en']` is invalid. You should read the manual, http://php.net/reserved.variables.get

Comment: your right, it is probably is not a dupe, but it is a very basic syntax error

Comment: @Sidharthpathak check my answer

Comment: `$GET['lang']` is also incorrect syntax. `$_GET['lang']` is the right one, as I mentioned above as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code.

```
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
if($lang=='en') 
{
 echo 'English';
}
else
{
    echo 'not english';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to the following. `$_GET` contains An associative array of variables passed to the current page via the URL parameters. So you have to get the variable and check if it is english or not.

```
if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
    $language = $_GET['lang'];
    if($language == 'en'){
        echo 'English';
    }else{
        echo 'not english';
    }
}else{ 
   echo "nothing";
}
```

Comment: You marked it as answer working. Then why would you removie it ? If you have any issues then you should ask here instead

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: It can't be not set and not empty at the same time. It is also redundant to check for both not empty and is set.

Comment: @Sidharthpathak please check now. There was a mistake in code. It was `isset()` not `!isset()`. Please check now

Comment: @Sidharthpathak i don't know about how to change the language of a page based on selected option. I have not done that. I have heard of `lang` attribute for html elements. Better you update your question with required data